# How to set password mode for popup edit in Kendo UI Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How can I format password input field of Kendo grid popup editing dialog to display password such as ...?
Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an [`editor`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.editor-Function) function to the `column` definition as follows:

```
editor: function (container, options) {
    $('<input data-text-field="' + options.field + '" ' +
            'class="k-input k-textbox" ' +
            'type="password" ' +
            'data-value-field="' + options.field + '" ' +
            'data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
}
```

You can even hide the column using [`columns.hidden`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.hidden-Boolean%28default) while not in edit mode doing:

```
{
    hidden: true,
    field : "password",
    title : "Password",
    editor: function (container, options) {
        $('<input data-text-field="' + options.field + '" ' +
                'class="k-input k-textbox" ' +
                'type="password" ' +
                'data-value-field="' + options.field + '" ' +
                'data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                .appendTo(container)
    }
} ,
```

Answer (score 4):

I would do it a little differently (for Popup editor). Add attribute just after the html is constructed.

Edit:
I've added example of how I add tooltips.

```
$(“#grid”).kendoGrid(
{
    …,
    edit: function( e )
    {
    //Add password attribute to input field.
        e.container.find( “.k-edit-field:eq(1) > input” ).attr( ‘type’, ‘password’ );

    //Add tooltip.
        e.container.find( "[data-label-for = name], [data-container-for = name]" ).attr('title', "One and two" ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tag your properties with attributes, one of these is; `[DataType(DataType.Password)]`. Apply this and you will get a control that is 'password formatted', similar to the below image.

[image]

For info the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387316/kendo-ui-mvc-popup-editor-how-to-hide-fields/13388032#13388032) gave me the idea of how to do this and may be useful to some too.